# Pattern not found: lastlevel = -1

Tags: folding

I'm getting one or more of these message when I open up a file I fold with a custom `foldexpr` function:

`Pattern not found: lastlevel = -1`

I'm not sure what's generating except the `lastlevel` variable is used in my fold function:

```
let g:lastlevel=0
function! Fold(lnum)
  " is line blank?
  if getline(a:lnum) =~? '\v^\s*$'
     if GetLevel(a:lnum + 1)
         g:lastlevel = -1
         return -1
     endif
     return g:lastlevel
  endif
  let last = g:lastlevel
  let num_of_pounds = GetLevel(a:lnum)
  if (num_of_pounds > 0)
     let g:lastlevel = num_of_pounds
     return '>' . num_of_pounds
  endif
  return g:lastlevel
endfunction

function! GetLevel(lnum)
  let pounds = strlen(matchstr(getline(a:lnum), '^#\+'))
  return pounds
endfunction
```

I also have this related autocommand:

```
augroup persist_markdown_folds
au!
autocmd BufWinLeave *.md mkview
autocmd BufWrite *.md mkview
autocmd BufEnter *.md set foldenable | set foldlevel=0 | set foldmethod=expr | set foldexpr=Fold(v:lnum) | loadview
autocmd BufNewFile *.md set foldenable | set foldlevel=0 | set foldmethod=expr | set foldexpr=Fold(v:lnum)
augroup end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
g:lastlevel = -1
```

`let` is missing. I suggest you use syntactic check plugin such as [ale](https://github.com/w0rp/ale) or [syntastic](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic) .

Comment: This answer would benefit from an explanation of why the given line caused the error (answer: `g:lastlevel` is a global command searching for lastlevel)